# Windows MySQL, Configure so that "run as admin" is not required

Tags: mysql, admin, startup, rights

I'm at work, I do not have admin rights and my IT department is significantly lacking... but I need MySQL to do my job more effectively (preferably WAMP). After 6 months of dealing with my IT department regarding this issue (an issue that would take me 30 minutes to solve if I had admin rights) I was able to have them install both WAMP and a discrete MySQL installation.

The problem is that I cannot run either without admin rights which apparently I'm not allowed to have.

The solution would be something along the lines:

1. **Configure WAMP or MySQL so that "run as admin" is not required (because doing so now prompts for admin user/pass).**
2. Configure MySQL or WAMP to start automatically on startup as admin, or.
3. Configure my username so that it has admin rights to only that one application, or.
4. Something else.

Some of the Errors trying to get MySQL to start:
[image]

Comment: VirtualBox may be an option.

Comment: a virtual machine might work, although installing virtualbox et al users requires admin rights in itself. You could use a free online host and do everything in the browser. Lots of choices: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=free+PHP+cloud+hosting&oq=free+php&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j69i65j0j69i60j0.4552j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#safe=active&q=free+PHP+hosting . Or google around for ways to install XAMPP or MAMP without admin rights - YMMV but there appear to be people trying.

Comment: I should ask though - does it need to specifically be this stack? Are you targeting deployment on another environment that needs PHP/MySQL, or are you just building tools for yourself? for instance I'm pretty sure SQLite doesn't require admin to run, there are ways of installing .NET Core without admin, and IDEs like Visual Studio Code and others don't need it. the PortableApps site might have non-admin installers for some coding tools pre-packaged - worth having a look.

Comment: P.S. I realise your situation is irritating (I've been in it) but I do sympathise with your IT dept. You want admin rights to perform a specific task, but they have to follow their governance and compliance processes, and since you're not in IT and therefore they've made no assessment of your general IT competence (through recruitment etc) they can't be sure that you'd use it responsibly, and you're likely outside their audit mechanisms etc. So they're perfectly correct to deny them to you in many ways.

Comment: The other issue from their point of view is, if you're coding tools for work purposes, and you're the only programmer in your dept, and the only one maintaining them, if you leave then chances are they will be asked to maintain code that they never agreed to support and haven't signed off or QA'd, with no knowledge of what it does or whether it's safe, or was developed by someone they deem competent. Plus it adds to their costs unexpectedly. Therefore they'll likely try to stop you doing this kind of thing. I've been you, it's incredibly frustrating, but in the end I just got a IT dept job...

Comment: ...because after having finally convinced them to give me a chance (with their oversight) what I wrote was better than anything their own devs managed to solve the same problem. So suddenly their mistrust changed into a keen desire to employ me. If you can't beat 'em, join 'em.

Comment: SQLite is currently used as a stop gap, but I ran into an issue where I learned relationships aren't enforced without a settings change... so all the relational data got screwed up because I was programming for months thinking the DB was enforcing but it wasn't. One of many issues caused by not using the target system MySQL to develop the software.

Comment: Interesting comments about IT and security processes... but the project has the blessing of top top brass and I work in a network security department. I'm not expressing frustration or an attempt to subvert security, I know their has to be a solution; a configuration setting that stops mysql from requiring admin rights.

Comment: Ok I see. The way your post was worded suggested you'd had a long running argument with your IT dept about doing dev work outside the dept. Perhaps I misunderstood. Anyway, it looks like you're trying to start it from the command prompt. Why haven't they configured MySql as a Windows service to run automatically when the machine starts? That ought to be sufficient - plenty of services on your box will run as admin without your intervention, and you can't switch them on or off, but you can make use of them. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/windows-start-service.html

Comment: Really I've had a long running argument with IT about getting off their butts to get this 6 month old ticket closed already. If they absolutely can't install it, I expect to be told why and helped with a workarround. Instead I get a message once a week now asking "has this issue been resolved", every week, and I have to bring another IT guy up to speed on the entire debacle. 1/10 IT guys will attempt to help on occation, by installing WAMP or MySQL, but in the end they don't appear to know the process of validation to get the software approved or deal with anything outside the norm.